# $Remote port in Nginx log file changes each time even it's from the same visitor

Tags: nginx, request, port

From the Nginx log file, it shows that the $remote_port (aka client port) changes every time even it's the same visitor visiting the same site :

```
180.163.220.3 - - [19/Jan/2020:14:18:07 +0800] "GET /home/images/logo.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 4997 "https://www.powerprocess.cn/home/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN"
180.163.220.3 - - [19/Jan/2020:14:18:07 +0800] "GET /home/images/banner.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 25161 "https://www.powerprocess.cn/home/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN"
180.163.220.3 - - [19/Jan/2020:14:18:07 +0800] "GET /home/images/about-us-team.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 58413 "https://www.powerprocess.cn/home/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN"
180.163.220.3 - - [19/Jan/2020:14:18:07 +0800] "GET /home/images/planning.svg HTTP/2.0" 200 10871 "https://www.powerprocess.cn/home/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN
```

As you can see, the port is changing, which I think shouldn't have been. Anyone can suggest the reason? Or maybe it's because although the visitor is visiting the same uri, the browser is actually making multiple requests to fetch the resources, and during each request the client port will be changed?

Comment: Is this a custom log format, because `$remote_port` is not present in the default access log, and it is not obvious which part of the log you are referring to? If the client does not or can not use HTTP persistent connections, then the remote port will change for each request.

Comment: It's a customised format with $remote_port added. Since I have different websites on multiple subdomains, the log is specially made for each site, which shows in the following format:`log_format  main  '$host $remote_addr - $remote_port - $http_host - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$server_port" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';`

Comment: That doesn't look like the snippet of the log you pasted into your question.